# End of the year date formula

Tags: formula, date

Need some help with a formula.
I have a start date field that the users have to fill out ( ex. 10.05.2015 ) but i
need a date field to  automatic fill out an End of the year date. It would always be the December 31, but the year have to be the same as the year of the start date.
Please help me ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DATE (YEAR (StartDate__c), 12, 31)
```