# how to write formula to get year end date based on system.today

Tags: formula, date

how to write formula to get year end date based on system.today.ForExample: if i open 1/1/2020 that field will be show 31/12/2020 like that i need formula

Comment: Duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/102316/59928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
DATE(Year(Today()),12,31)
```